# ASP.NET CORE and BLAZOR : Reset Password

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity, razor-components

Hy,

I'm new to blazor and .net and was wondering how i can implement a password reset the best way possible.
Currently i'm using this example to login etc : [Blazor Authentication Sample](https://github.com/christiansparre/BlazorAuthenticationSample).
This example excludes an example for reseting the password.So i was searching for a solution myself.

This is what is have, it's a Razor Component

```
@page "/ResetPassword"

@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider

@if (IsResetSend)
{
    <h3>Reset Password</h3>
    <div>
        A mail has been send with a password reset link, please click this link to set a new password.
    </div>
    <br />
    <a href="/">Back</a>
}
else
{
    <h3>Reset Password</h3>
    <EditForm Model="resetPassword" OnValidSubmit="@SendResetPassword">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">E-mail</label>
            <div class="control">
                <InputText id="email" class="input" type="email" @bind-Value="@resetPassword.Email"></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}

@code {

    ResetPassword resetPassword = new ResetPassword();

    bool IsResetSend = false;

    public async void SendResetPassword()
    {
        List<string> mailTo = new List<string>();

        string passwordResetToken;

        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(resetPassword.Email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            mailTo.Add(resetPassword.Email);

            passwordResetToken = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

            //Send mail with the relevant token
            Webco.Email.Entities.EmailObject emailObject = new Webco.Email.Entities.EmailObject();
            emailObject.Email_To = mailTo;
            emailObject.Email_Subject = "Password Reset Webco !";
            emailObject.Email_Message = "Hy There, <br> Please click this link to reset your password : <br> https://localhost:44384/" + passwordResetToken;
            emailObject.SendEmail(emailObject);

            IsResetSend = true;
        }
    }

    public class ResetPassword
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

As you can see, this is a staightforward approach, currently the one thing i can't seem to find is a way to store the password reset token, and capture it when it is being clicked in the mail.

Before i would;

1. Create a random token, store it in the database in the field ;
   UserResetToken of the current user
2. When the user then click's the link, the token would be offered to the webpage [Parameter].
3. A stored procedure would then find the token and clear it, to alter the password afterwards on another user form.

I don't think this is best practice there it is based on a custom stored procedure. Could anybody guide me in this ?

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Blazor has all required examples already included. Create a new project and choose as authentication In-App Storage. Click with the right mouse button on your project and choose Add->New Scaffolding element and choose Identity on the right. Visual Studio will ask you which files you want to override and creates a full example which you can use to build it in your main app.

This pages are possible:
[image]

Comment: Trying this but want to switch from SQL Svr  to SQLite. Option is there but can't click it.

Answer (score 3):

After some searching, and thanks to the response of Marvin i came to the code bellow. 
Maybe it can help anybody who searches for this topic. 
Open for improvement...

I tested this at a server side application in development. Not on iis

Link for understanding the usermanager 
[kudvenkat, great youtube series on .net core](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72Eu92ZkgCg)

**Razor Component**

```
@page "/ResetPassword"

@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
@using System.Text;

@* THIS IS THE PART HANDLING THE RESET TOKEN INCOMING VALIDATION *@
@if (IsResetToken)
{

    <h3>Reset Password</h3>
    <div>
        Please enter a new Password bellow;
    </div>
    <br />
    <EditForm Model="@validatePasswordModel" OnValidSubmit="@SetResetPassword">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Password</label>
            <div class="control">
                <InputText id="password" class="input" type="password" @bind-Value="@validatePasswordModel.Password"></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Confirm password</label>
            <div class="control">
                <InputText id="cpassword" class="input" type="password" @bind-Value="@validatePasswordModel.ConfirmPassword"></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Set Password</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
    <br />
    <a href="/">Back</a>

}
else
{

    @* THIS IS THE PART HANDLING THE RESET TOKEN OUTGOING VALIDATION *@

    @if (IsResetSend)
    {
        <h3>Reset Password</h3>
        <div>
            A mail has been send with a password reset link, please click this link to set a new password.
        </div>
        <br />
        <a href="/">Back</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <h3>Reset Password</h3>
        <EditForm Model="requestPasswordModel" OnValidSubmit="@SendResetPassword">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">E-mail</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <InputText id="email" class="input" type="email" @bind-Value="@requestPasswordModel.Email"></InputText>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    }
}

@code {

    InputModel requestPasswordModel = new InputModel();
    ResetPasswordModel validatePasswordModel = new ResetPasswordModel();

    string email = "";
    string token = "";

    bool IsResetSend = false;
    bool IsResetToken = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        GetHttpParameters();

    }

    public void GetHttpParameters()
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(navigationManager.Uri);
        var httpQuery = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

        email = httpQuery["email"] ?? "";
        token = httpQuery["token"] ?? "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            IsResetToken = true;

        }
    }

    public async void SendResetPassword()
    {
        List<string> mailTo = new List<string>();

        string passwordResetToken;
        string passwordResetUrl;

        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(requestPasswordModel.Email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            passwordResetUrl = navigationManager.BaseUri;

            passwordResetToken = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

            passwordResetToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordResetToken));

            passwordResetUrl = "https://localhost:44384/ResetPassword?email=" + user.Email + "&token=" + passwordResetToken;

            mailTo.Add(requestPasswordModel.Email);

            //Send mail with the relevant token
            Webco.Email.Entities.EmailObject emailObject = new Webco.Email.Entities.EmailObject();
            emailObject.Email_To = mailTo;
            emailObject.Email_Subject = "Password Reset Webco !";
            emailObject.Email_Message = $"Hy There, <br> Please click this link to reset your password : <br><a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(passwordResetUrl)}'> clikcing here </a>.";
            emailObject.SendEmail(emailObject);

            IsResetSend = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //it's a lie
            IsResetSend = true;
        }
    }

    public async void SetResetPassword()
    {
        List<string> mailTo = new List<string>();

        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            token = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token));

            var result = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, validatePasswordModel.ConfirmPassword);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                mailTo.Add(email);

                //Send mail with the relevant token
                Webco.Email.Entities.EmailObject emailObject = new Webco.Email.Entities.EmailObject();
                emailObject.Email_To = mailTo;
                emailObject.Email_Subject = "Password Reset Webco !";
                emailObject.Email_Message = $"Hy There, <br> You password was just reset at webco. Not you ? <br> Contact webco for support.";
                emailObject.SendEmail(emailObject);

                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/LoginUserResetPasswordComplete", true);
            }
            else
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/LoginUserResetPasswordError", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/LoginUserResetPasswordError",true);
        }

    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResetPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Compare(nameof(Password))]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

}
```